# Material-ui List - Module not found: 'react'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Good afternoon,

I just followed the whole React official tutorial, my tic-tac-toe game works. Then I wanted to add some material-ui components. I installed it via :

```
npm install --save @material-ui/core
npm install --save @material-ui/icons
```

I can get this to work :

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
[...]
<Button variant="contained" color="primary">Hello World</Button>
```

But I can't find why I cannot import List :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
```

I get this error :

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ../~/@material-ui/core/List/List.js
Module not found: 'react' in /home/myuser/myproject/node_modules/@material-ui/core/List

 @ ../~/@material-ui/core/List/List.js 16:36-52
```

React and material-ui versions are :

```
grep version node_modules/react/package.json 
  "version": "16.13.1"
grep version node_modules/@material-ui/core/package.json 
  "version": "4.11.0"
```

The line causing the error in List.js is :

```
var React = _interopRequireWildcard(require("react"));
```

Any pointers to how I can solve this ?

Comment: Not sure why this happens, could you please try remove `node_modules` folder and `npm install` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @ShinaBR2 :)

I don't know what happened, but after I deleted the whole node_modules directory and re-installed everything, it worked.

```
rm -Rf node_modules
npm install
```